# Аппроксимация экспериментальных данных

Tags: r

Есть данные для графика(x,y), если его построить, то видно,что где-то есть возрастание, а где-то убывание. Нужно находить на каком интервале убывает, а на каком возрастает и складировать в вектора данные интервалы. Далее нужно аппроксимировать экспонентами данные интервалы. 
Так вот, я как бывший фортранист, начал бы в цикле все элементы просматривать и какой `min/max` сохранять и тд, но я как понимаю, в R - это глупо. Как еще можно?

А второй вопрос наиболее актуален. Если я хочу вот эти экспериментальные данные, предположим возрастающую часть, аппроксимировать двумя экспонентами `(A1*exp(B1*x/t1)+A2*exp(B2*x/t2))`,  то есть использовать nls, мне нужно задать начальные параметры. Если я их задаю по [примеру](http://robinlovelace.net/2013/10/23/nls-demonstation.html) 1, то у меня выдает, что-то типо сингулярная градиентная матрица, как правильно "подогнать"?

Comment: Чтобы понять, где убывает и где возрастает, нужно найти точки экстремума функции. Но раз функцию, описывающую зависимость, мы не знаем, то можно построить график и выделить эти участки визуально.

Comment: Автор, у вас ссылка на данные сломалась.

Answer (score 2):

На счет возрастания/убывания можно сделать что то наподобие вот такой функции

```
df <- data.frame(year=c(1,2,2,3,4,1,6,3,4,2))


test <- function(x,n) {
  if(x==1) return( NA)
  else{  if (df[x,n]<df[x-1,n])    return ("UP")
  else           return ("DOWN")}
}
a=1:nrow(df)
df$b=unlist(lapply(a, FUN=function(i) test(i,1)))
```

А потом отфильтровать по UP\DOWN

Comment: Спасибо, как оказалось, программно реализовать участки возрастания-убывания сложно, поэтому все делалось в полуавтоматическом режиме

Answer (score 1):

По поводу выделения интервалов, на которых функция возрастает или убывает:

```
f <- function(x, y) {
    d <- diff(y)
    list(up = x[which(d > 0)],
         down = x[which(d < 0)],
         non = x[which(d == 0)])
}
x <- 1:10
y <- c(3:1, 1:5, 4:5)
f(x, y)
#> $up
#> [1] 4 5 6 7 9
#> 
#> $down
#> [1] 1 2 8
#> 
#> $non
#> [1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Определить можно просто указав знак первой производной т.е.
    require(magrittr);
    s <- diff(y) %>% sign() %>% c(NA,.);
Получим вектор состоящий из 1 и -1, которые явно указывают возрастающие и убывающие участки переменной y.
Удачи
ПС: Не нашел как вставить код, сори.
  В ответе приведенном ниже есть ошибка, которая часто остается незамеченной
    d <- diff(y) %>% c(0,.)
При вычислении первой разницы мы получаем вектор короче исходного на 1. Для получения в последующем верных индексов, нужно удлинить вектор на 1. Иначе в последствии  будут ошибки. Так в примере ниже максимальный индекс x = 9 а должен быть 10.